# Win32 buttons (BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON) have shadow until at least one button gets focused

Tags: winapi, button, focus, border, shadow

Pretty much the title. When I start the application the buttons have a shadow/dark outline. But when I focus any one of them, all of them lose this shadow/outline.
Is there something I can do to make them have a consistent look? Either one would be fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you deliberately using the old common controls? If not, see [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview) on how to opt-in to using the version 6 common controls.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I managed to get the modern common controls to work, but the problem persists. It's just a different color now. With the modern common controls the outline is blue instead of black, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: In that case it would help to see a [mcve]. Maybe there's something wrong in a place you didn't even consider to be part of this.